# Toddler stuttering

Tags: toddler, language-development

My son is 34 months old and has all of a sudden started stuttering. He usually has difficulty starting sentences beginning with "I" but recently he has difficulty with other words as well, mostly at the start of a sentence. I spoke to an SLP from a well known institute in Dubai and was advised that its a natural occurrence and will pass with time. She advised me not to bring him in immediately. However, it still concerns me and I was hoping for some inputs from other parents. Thanks very much in advance

Mia

Comment: The accepted answer on this other question is very good, and I think it answers your question, and provides some reassurance. http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-should-we-address-stuttering-in-a-toddler?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both my Kids did it at some point between 3 and 5 years for a couple of days / weeks. It went away on its own, maybe it's something to do with their development, I am not sure.

But nothing to worry about.

I would say if it goes on for more than 2-4 weeks, you can start thinking about going to a doc, but I am sure it will go away on its own.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reassurance. We will watch closely and follow the tips on the other thread.